# Should we get a vector logo?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Right now, we use a raster logo instead of a vector logo.

For those who don't know, a raster is an image made of pixels. If you zoom enough, you'll see the image become pixelated (as is the case with our logo). Vector graphics don't become pixelated when you zoom into them, and they'll always remain crisp.

Almost every SE site uses vector logos because they look nicer. An example of a vector graphic is this:

[image]
<sup>Feynmann diagram is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Feynmann_Diagram_Gluon_Radiation.svg), courtesy of user [Joel Holdsworth](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Joelholdsworth~commonswiki) under [the Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 Generic license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/deed.en). Modified by changing the color and trimming the gluon spiral. Logo based on Physics SE's logo, copyright of Stack Exchange Inc.; no infringement intended.</sup>

I made this in a few minutes. Notice how it does not pixelate when you zoom in. Not to mention, the current logo shows up blurry for a lot of larger displays. Shouldn't we update our design to have better quality?

PS: If you decide to use the logo I made, please give attribution to the creator of the Feynmann diagram, as per the Creative Commons license.

Comment: The SE design team is perfectly aware of the distinction, and questioning their design choices based on incomplete information is not normally very productive. Are there in-practice instances where the logo shows up under-resolved? What real-world impact would your proposed change have?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty What real world impact does any design have? No design is intended to affect the world, they only make websites more visually appealing. Also, I'm not criticizing their design choices with incomplete information, it's a simple suggestion. If you have a legitimate reason to disagree, please speak. That would at least be productive.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Given that smaller sites like Bicycle SE use vector logos, it doesn't really seem like an intentional flaw. It is definitely something they forgot to implement here. If you know any good reason as to why they didn't use a vector logo here then say it. Otherwise your comment looks too naive.

Comment: You're not proposing any change to the design, and you're not offering any evidence that your proposed change would actually change how the site looks. So, again: can you offer any evidence that the logo appears under-resolved in *any* circumstances? Or why are you so keen on zooming in on the logo? It looks perfectly fine in its intended magnification. Without that, both comments above are making a lot of naive hullabaloo about very little.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty [Sure, here](https://i.imgur.com/B2Ylz3h.png). The logo is blurry on a big display screen like mine. I don't want to hear "it was intended to be blurry".

Comment: ^ Yeah, it's blurry on mine too. @EmilioPisanty Now, please don't ask why the logo being blurry bothers us. Or, if it were less blurry, what "real-world" impact it would have.

Comment: Then edit that onto the question and say "the logo is blurry in high-dpi screens, please make it vector graphics" instead of "I think the design team should do more work but I can't be bothered to say why". Vector graphics are a tool where you need to be taking about effects. I honestly don't see how any of this is controversial, and I don't see how responding with snark to requests for evidence and clarity is "productive".

Comment: @EmilioPisanty "I think the design team should do more work but I can't be bothered to say why" **SirCumference never claimed that**. "I don't see how responding with snark to requests for evidence and clarity is "productive"".... **I don't see which comment seems to be a snark to you** Be specific. Secondly, anyone with common sense would realize that the logo would look pixelated in high resolution displays. (Given that SirC already said: "Notice how it does not **pixelate when you zoom in**. Shouldn't we update our design to have **better quality**?").

Comment: @EmilioPisanty FYI in your last but one comment 'It looks perfectly find in its intended magnification'. I think you are forgetting that some people may need to magnify images, e.g. due to visual impairment. If the magnified image is pixelated I can imagine this doesn't help them a great deal.  For evidence - try turning on your device accessibility magnifier and see the difference.

Comment: I think it's clear that vector graphics are always better than non-vector. They simply can be used in any situation perfectly. It doesn't matter if you will actually use it, it just increases the range of options you have. Also @SirCumference is sharing his work here, not demanding a vector graphics from SE design team. Also, could you export it to pdf or eps? I thing it's more likely that people can open it in their computer than with svg. I need GIMP for that, and when I open the image, GIMP rasters it with a resolution it asks for. Is there any reason why you used svg?

Comment: Could it be because internet browser compatibility? I don't know if they have problems with pdf's.

Comment: @anonymous: they're SVGs, not PDFs. And it's unlikely due to browser compatibility. [All modern browsers support SVG](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg). Some old browsers don't, but it's entirely possible for the site to implement a PNG-fallback for those browsers (if they're deemed worth the effort).

Comment: This SVG logo you have here is 81 kB. If I run it through `svg-cleaner` it cuts it down to 44 kB. If I `gzip -9` it, it's down to 16 kB. However, [the PNG](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/physics/img/logo.png?v=fef712181a47) is only 5 kB. It would be nice to have a crisp vector logo/banner, but I hope we can clean it up even more and shave a few more kB off. I know it's only a few kB, but this is how bloat happens (it's totally worth it, but still, good effort needs to be put into minimizing the SVG). Also, +2 for the pretty SVG (but -1 for no red free-hand circle).

Comment: @SirCumference Regarding your edit, that's completely upside down. The site logo is *not* under a CC license - all the site design assets are SE copyright (and only user-provided content is CC), as the footer will inform you. From a formalist perspective, your SVG version is already infringing copyright (and no, it doesn't matter if you recreated it from scratch). There's no "we" in updating the logo file - it is all owned and managed by Stack Exchange.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Mine is infringing copyright? Read the terms: I must give attribution and make it clear what changes were made.

Comment: @SirCumference You're not infringing the Wikipedia image copyright - you're infringing (formally speaking) Stack Exchange copyright by making new copies of their assets. And no, it doesn't matter that it's you making new copies, you're still copying existing assets. I don't think they'll mind, but insisting on attribution on something that's already infringing is a bit bizarre.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Oye, all right.

Comment: Nope, that's still not it (v4). The site logo is *not* under CC BY-SA, it is copyright of Stack Exchange, period, and not released under any license. Read the footer and the ToS; the only CC content is the user-provided content.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty So it's not as simple as "give attribution"? Fun.

Comment: No, it's not as simple as "give attribution". One thing *is* simple, though: do not misrepresent the copyright status of the materials you're using (as the current (v4) version does).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I suppose I'll wait and see if they mind.

Comment: Shouldn't we contact someone responsible for this issue? Maybe Jin: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201772/222044

Comment: @jinawee The SE team monitors all posts tagged feature-request on the meta sites - you can rest assured that they are aware of this post and will respond if they have something to say.

Comment: With all the fuss about the copyright, I'd add that "no infringement intended" is a completely pointless phrase. Whether you intend to commit copyright infringement or not has no bearing on whether you actually do. Also, I doubt that a generic Feynman diagram is worthy of copyright protection, so I don't think it would be legally required to credit Joel for using the same diagram in a design. (If nothing else, the diagram _already_ appears in the current site logo.) I'm all for respecting copyright and not saying you did something _wrong_ by offering an attribution, I just think it's overkill.

Comment: "Almost every SE site uses vector logos because they look nicer" s/look nicer/are simpler to make/ Fixed that for you

Comment: Looks like this is going to be fixed with the new left-nav design: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10784/physics-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing